# Bash, get substring by keeping the match with awk

Tags: bash, awk

How can I split a string with awk but printing the match too?

Full random string:

```
aaa sasawf wewfTotemeswdwqewqwqtotemwewedew
```

I need to get "wewftotemeswdwqewqwqtotemwewedew" where the substring is random, the only constant is a space and the word totem in it. As you notice the random string might contain more than one totem word, I need awk to get the substring starting from the first match. To be clear, I need "wewftotemeswdwqewqwqtotemwewedew" not "totemwewedew". I also need it to be case insensitive

I can use `awk -F ' .*totem' '{print$2}'` to print `eswdwqewqwqtotemwewedew` but how can I print the match too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for the third arg to match():

```
$ echo 'aaa sasawf wewftotemeswdwqewqwq' |
    awk 'match($0,/[^ ]*totem[^ ]*/,a) { print a[0] }'
wewftotemeswdwqewqwq
```

and with any awk:

```
$ echo 'aaa sasawf wewftotemeswdwqewqwq' |
    awk 'match($0,/[^ ]*totem[^ ]*/) { print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }'
wewftotemeswdwqewqwq
```

For case-insensitive matching with GNU awk:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 'match($0,/[^ ]*totem[^ ]*/...
```

and with any awk:

```
awk 'match(tolower($0),/[^ ]*totem[^ ]*/...
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to stop it at the first match?

Comment: The answer to `Is there any way` is almost always "yes" but there's several things `stop it at the first match` might mean (first in a file, first in a paragraph, first on a line, first in a word, etc.). Just adding `;exit` after the print statement MIGHT be all you want, idk. If this doesn't do what you want then update your question to more clearly state your requirements and provide a better example that truly demonstrates what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Ed, I have updated my question. It looks like $ echo 'aaa sasawf wewftotemeswdwqewqwq' |
    awk 'match($0,/[^ ]*totem[^ ]*/) { print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }' works fine for me, however it only works for lower case. Is there a way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: The answer to `Is there a way to` is almost always "yes". Please make the sample input in your question mixed-case since that's what you want to test.

Comment: Your last command works fine, I only need to edit it in order to have that working as case insensitive. Can you please assist?

Comment: Done but when you want a script that's doing case-insensitive matching, the example you post in your question should include mix-case strings so that when we come up with a potential solution we have that example to test against.